# Hourly average except when hour has only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which works on SQL Server 2012 to give me the hourly average of the values in the `CounterValue` column:

```
select 
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0), 
    avg(CounterValue) 
from mopsxactthroughput 
group by 
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0)
```

I would like to, if possible, modify it so that it returns no row for an hour if there was only ONE record matching that hour.  For example, if between 2013-06-06T20:00:00 and 2013-06-06T21:00:00 there was only one record, I want no row returned for that one hour period.

It strikes me as a little much to ask for of a `SELECT`, but maybe there is a way.  (My fallback will be to return all records grouped by hour and then iterate the row set myself in Java and apply the averaging/discarding there.)

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(*)>1` or `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN CounterDateTime BETWEEN '2013-06-06T20:00:00' AND '2013-06-06T21:00:00' THEN 1 END)>1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `having` clause:

```
select 
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0), 
    avg(CounterValue) 
from mopsxactthroughput 
group by 
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0)
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this CTE works:

```
with cte as( 
    select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0) as Hour, 
           avg(CounterValue)over(partition by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0)) as AvgCounter,
           Count(*)over(partition by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CounterDateTime), 0)) as HourCount,
           CounterValue,
           CounterDateTime
    from mopsxactthroughput 
)
select Hour, CounterValue, CounterDateTime, AvgCounter
from cte
where HourCount > 1
```

Comment: Looks like it did the trick.  I have to comb through the results to be sure then I will accept your answer thanks.